# R Efficiency - Travelling Salesman Problem Algorithm

Tags: r, performance

I am relatively new to R and required to create a code for the travelling salesman problem using random insertion. I think it works, but it is so slow and it should be much faster. Is there any way to improve it?

So, starting with 3 random cities another random city is picked which is inserted between the cities where the total cost is the lowest.

This is my code:

```
RandomInsertionTSP <- function(instance){

    #Function takes a distance matrix
    X <- instance

    #Randomly picking the cities for insertion
    index <- sample(1:ncol(X))
    
    #Initializing the permutation vector and determining the first 3 cities from index
    perm <- rep(0, ncol(X))
    perm[1:3] <- index[1:3]
    
    #Intializing the min distance vector and determining the first 3 min distances
    min <- rep(0, ncol(X))

    min[1:3] <- diag(X[perm[1:3], perm[c(2:3,1)]])
    
    
    for (i in 4:ncol(X)){
        
        #Calculating the insertion cost for index[i]
        insertion.cost <- X[perm[1:(i-1)],index[i]] + X[perm[c(2:(i-1),1)],index[i]] - min[1:(i-1)]
        #Determining the insertion location 
        insertion.location <- 1 + which.min(insertion.cost)[1]
        
        #Creating a new perm and min vector with the results
        temp <- perm
        perm[insertion.location] <- index[i]
        perm[(insertion.location + 1):length(perm)] <- temp[insertion.location:(length(temp)-1)]
        min[1:i] <- diag(X[perm[1:i], perm[c(2:i,1)] ])
    }
    # Returning a list with the permutation and cost
    return(list(perm, sum(min)))

}
```

I tried to avoid loops but I can't think of a way to avoid the for-loop at all. I tried to keep the commands within the for loop as efficient as possible. Maybe there are things exclude from the loop, but I can't think of any. I am required to use base R.

Comment: on its face your function can't work. it requires a parameter called instance to be passed in that, it doesnt use.. it immediately tries to use something called X. I think you need to address such issues, before asking for performance related support.

Comment: You are right thanks! That was a copy-paste issue. Edited it.

Comment: you should also consider providing an example of how your function might be used, i.e. an example of how you create instance to be passed in. I tried using dist() and then as.matrix(dist) and didnt progress to test your function with either...

Comment: you can read about https://dirkschumacher.github.io/ompr/articles/problem-tsp.html and https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/TSP/TSP.pdf

Comment: Can you give a reproducible example of an `instance`?